# How do I get larger text to line up directly against a div in FireFox?

Tags: css, text, html

```
    div.faq1 {
    font-size: 175px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans Serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}
```

So I am trying to figure out how to get the text "FAQ" to line up against either a container div or within this div itself.

I've also tried creating a regular div and then using the span tag to style the text but it continues to show a top and left margin of some sort regardless of if I use:

```
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: unclear... What do you mean line up against a div?

Comment: Create a JSFiddle with an example

Comment: an image that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve would be better for our understanding

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the text is actually that size (has that extra padding at the top and bottom of the text, double click the text and you will see the actual boundaries).  But to accomplish more of what you want to do, you could add in the following:

line-height:75%;

That should help you achieve what you want.

EDIT:

noticed you wanted the left too .. use this

text-indent:-14px;

Comment: Adamn, your solution is what I need.  Thank you.  I apologize to the rest regarding providing an image of what the wanted outcome would be.  I will remember this the next time.  I had problems with negative margins, thinking that was the solution.  I kept seeing that the div would just be pushed out but it would give me what I wanted.  But I had a feeling that this could lead to future problems.  The text-indent works great.  Thanks again!.

Answer (score 0):

It also helps if you want to align anything in the div to a side by adding the follow code to the specified div.

```
div.faq1 {
    font-size: 175px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans Serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: (left, center, right);
}
```

But then again, that could not be what you are asking for. Hope that helped.